# another rotten puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

[image]

Transcript:

```
V G V F N Z H F V A
T U B J F V Z C Y R
G U V A T F P N A T
B H A A B G V P R Q
V S Q V F T H V F R
Q V A G U R P B E E
R P G J N L G B F R
R Z Y V X R F B Z R
G U V A T I R E L P
B Z C Y V P N G R Q
```

> Did it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is

> [ROT-13](https://rot13.com/) for
>  **It is amusing how simple things can go unnoticed if disguised
>  in the correct way to seem like something very complicated.**
>
>  As clued by **ROT**ten (but why ROT-13 and not ROT-10?)

Normally I would expect more steps to find the final answer, but since there is no other information in the puzzle to follow, I guess this is it.

Comment: Hopefully there is more to it, this seems a little too straightforward.

Comment: Also agree about rot-10 which was my first instinct